# If I restore default settings on my ps3 will my gameshared games be deleted?

Tags: ps3

If I restore default settings on my ps3 will my gameshared games be deleted ?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you mean by "default settings". If you completely reset your PS3 and clear the system then all of your accounts and saved data will be purged from the hard drive including any "game shared" data. For what it's worth though, game sharing is a terms of service violation and risks having your PS3 banned from accessing the PlayStation Network.